# Moment.js - Exact time til moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, momentjs

Let's say that i have a moment object that is 20 hours ahead of now, and i want to display how long from the current time i have to wait to reuse a command. `.fromNow()` gives me a result of `In a day` Which tells me absolutely nothing. what is the simplest way to get something like `In [x] hours, [y] Minutes`?

#### Current Code

```js
message.channel.send(`You already claimed your reward.\nCheck back ${moment(nd).fromNow()}`) // "In a day"
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `a.diff(b, 'minutes')` and calculate the hours yourself

Answer (score -1):

A common way of displaying time is handled by moment#fromNow. This is sometimes called time ago or relative time.

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago
```

If you pass true, you can get the value without the suffix.

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow();     // 4 years ago
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(true); // 4 years
```

Try this

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
a.from(b);
```